# Disable SVG previews for asset field?

Tags: assets, control-panel, image-transforms, bug, svg

A client of mine uploads multiple, complex SVGs (2MB and larger) to an asset field. Unfortunately, Craft CMS isn't able to automatically generate thumbnail images (with a reduced filesize, not just rescaled!). As a result, the control panel pages for entries render unbearably slow or even crash in the browser, as all SVGs are loaded into the same view.

Is it possible to set up Craft to display a generic icon for SVGs instead?

Comment: Please consider upvoting my related [feature request](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/17738419-for-assets-in-craft-don-t-preview-svg-files-per-d)!

Comment: I would call this a bug as it’s breaking the CP for you. Upvoted the feature request nevertheless…